# Hide (or dim) Android Wear Charging Icon

Tags: android, watch-face-api

I created an Android Wear watch face with specialized content for when the smart watch is in its charging cradle, such that it makes a reasonable bedside clock overnight. We use big super-dim digits in this mode for comfortable night viewing (& display preservation). It's astonishing how annoyingly bright the tiny little charging icon is on some watches! Using the `setWatchFaceStyle` API and `setStatusBarGravity` I have (very limited) control over where it's positioned on the screen, but I can't find a way to eliminate or dim it. I assume Wear is designed on some level not to let individual watch faces screw up system icons, but I'm hoping there's a way nonetheless. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Method called `setHideStatusBar(boolean hideStatusBar)`. This will hide any status information on your watchface.

Comment: This method is not documented, but is certainly the answer to OP's question. Not sure why it was downvoted. It is perhaps only slated for release with Wear OS 2.3. As such, it may not be respected on older devices.